# Javascript <select> styling - Firefox places select after span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am trying to use Adam Coulombe's jQuery Custom Select (http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/) on a web application I am developing.

I have managed to implement the solution and it works perfectly in Chrome, Opera and IE, but Firefox (v25) places the select box after the span styling, making the select box dysfunctional.

Another issue with Firefox I've experienced is when I change the value of the select box the value of the select doesn't appear to change. Here is an image demonstrating what I mean:

[image]

The code for the select box span:

```
.select-thin { height: 25px!important; border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2); border-radius: 2px; line-height: 25px; padding: 0 0 0 5px; width: 100%; background: url('../images/down-arrow.png') 90% center no-repeat; }
```

Driving me up the wall since it's the last part of the page that needs fixing and it works in every browser except Firefox. Help very much appreciated.

**Solution**

*I can't answer my question for several hours so here is the solution.*

There appears to be some incompatibilities which mean you cannot place a custom select box inside of an anchor () tag. After playing with the code and taking the select box outside of the anchor tags things worked perfectly.

Comment: please try to replicate issue on jsFiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ueYL2/3/ - This returns the same issue in Firefox for me.

Comment: For me, it doesn't work at all on FF (v25)

Comment: Try clicking just to the very right hand side of the visible select box. There's a tiny click window between the end of the select span and the end of the list item where you can open the select menu.

Comment: Hm... You are putting the `<select>` inside an `<a>` element, which is not correct. Interactive elements like that should never be nested. Does it work when you take the `<select>` out of the `<a>`?